# How to show array json string

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am trying to show the data from a json string.

I have tried this:

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var thepds, x = "";

        thepds = {"end-point": "/api/sample/", "products": [{"is_customizable": "0", "delivery": "1-2 dage", "kids": "0", "name": "the name", "sizes": "37-39, 40-42, 43-45, 46-48", "kid_adult": "1", "free_porto": "0", "image": "image.png", "package": "0", "price": "119,00", "url": "theurl", "online": "1", "price_old": "119,00", "currency": "dkk", "img_url": "image.jpg", "id": "153339", "women": "0"}, {"is_customizable": "0", "delivery": "1-2 dage", "kids": "0", "name": "the name", "sizes": "37-39, 40-42, 43-45, 46-48", "kid_adult": "1", "free_porto": "0", "image": "image.png", "package": "0", "price": "119,00", "url": "theurl", "online": "1", "price_old": "119,00", "currency": "dkk", "img_url": "image.jpg", "id": "153339", "women": "0"}]};
        for (i in thepds.products) {
            x += "<h1>" + thepds.products[i].delivery + "</h1>";

        }
        document.getelementbyid("demo").innerhtml = x;

    </script>
```

But it doesn't show anything.

Comment: innerhtml should be innerHTML. Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: `getelementbyid()` should be `getElementById()`, `innerhtml` should be `innerHTML`. *Voting to close as "Simple typographical error"*.

Comment: I have changed your question to a snippet. This may help you see the issue.

Comment: Second to the answers above (check your case sensitivity) you might look into AngularJS, it's a perfect tool for this kind of thing, and doesn't require loops.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);` will be useful (pretty print JSON object with 2 spaces as an indentation), the issue with converting newlines to `<br/>` and maintaining the spacing still stands

Comment: Thanks guys, i am glad it was that simple. Javascript is case sensitive noted! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the case of the innerHTML property. The correct one would be:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Javascript is a case sensitive language.

Comment: In the future, consider submitting a close vote rather than an answer for questions of this nature. There is a specific closure reason for "simple typographical errors".

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive. So `getelementbyid` and `innerhtml` should be as follows

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var thepds, x = "";

        thepds = {"end-point": "/api/sample/", "products": [{"is_customizable": "0", "delivery": "1-2 dage", "kids": "0", "name": "the name", "sizes": "37-39, 40-42, 43-45, 46-48", "kid_adult": "1", "free_porto": "0", "image": "image.png", "package": "0", "price": "119,00", "url": "theurl", "online": "1", "price_old": "119,00", "currency": "dkk", "img_url": "image.jpg", "id": "153339", "women": "0"}, {"is_customizable": "0", "delivery": "1-2 dage", "kids": "0", "name": "the name", "sizes": "37-39, 40-42, 43-45, 46-48", "kid_adult": "1", "free_porto": "0", "image": "image.png", "package": "0", "price": "119,00", "url": "theurl", "online": "1", "price_old": "119,00", "currency": "dkk", "img_url": "image.jpg", "id": "153339", "women": "0"}]};
        for (i in thepds.products) {
            x += "<h1>" + thepds.products[i].delivery + "</h1>";

        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    </script>
```

Comment: In the future, consider submitting a close vote rather than an answer for questions of this nature. There is a specific closure reason for "simple typographical errors".

Comment: @Santi Sure. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Not an issue at all, just pointing it out for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

Even me having trouble with typographical errors. But we are here to help each other.

The line
document.getelementbyid("demo").innerhtml = x;

should be
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

Don't be discouraged to asked anything again. And don't try to discourage anyone to ask.

Comment: In the future, consider submitting a close vote rather than an answer for questions of this nature. There is a specific closure reason for "simple typographical errors".